# Find average speed in same time intervals

Tags: php

I had two vectors. One has the time and other the speed values. I need to get the average speed value of same time intervals.
ex.

```
$time=array('18:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:15:00', '19:15:00', '20:30:00');
$v=array(10, 20, 30, 70, 60);
```

I need to get the vector: `$v_optimized(15, 50, 60)`; 
The value '15' is the average speed of values `10` and `20` in `$v`, corresponding to same times '`18:00:00`' and so on for all values.

I've written this code, but i'm missing something. Please somebody help me.

```
$time=array('18:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:15:00', '19:15:00', '20:30:00');
$v=array(10, 20, 30, 70, 60);
$time_opt= array();
$v_opt= array();
$start=0;
$count=0;
$end=0;
$sum=0;
$nr=count($time);
for($i=0; $i<$nr-2; $i++){
for($j=$i+1; $j<$nr-1; $j++){
$start = $i;

if($time[$j]==$time[$j+1]){
$time_opt[$i]=$time[$i];
$count++;
$sum+= $v[$j];
}
else{
$avg = $sum / $count;
array_push($v_opt, $avg);
//$count = 0;
}
}}
for($k=0;$k<count($v_opt); $k++)
echo $v_opt[$k].'<br>';
```

Comment: not understood what you want!!

Comment: I need to optimize the speed values is second vector to get the average of each interval. An interval is a group of different speeds with the same time (first vector).  
The values are as corresponding:
`$time[0]=>'18:00:00'  with $v[0]=> '10'
$time[1]=>'18:00:00'  with $v[1]=> '20'`
... and so on
for the first interval i need to get the average speed, which is 15, in this case... and continue for other intervals.

Comment: ok like `first interval` avg of time will be `15` `second interval` avg of time will be `25`?

Comment: At the first vector of times there are 3 intervals:
first: `'18:00:00'`
second: `'19:15:00'`
third: `'20:30:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand this is what you want .. Give it a Try

```
<?php

        $time=array('18:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:15:00', '19:15:00', '20:30:00');
        $v=array(10, 20, 30, 70, 60);

        // get total of vector for a given time
        $temp_arr = array();

        foreach($time as $key=>$value)
        {
           $temp_arr[$value] = $temp_arr[$value]+$v[$key] ;
        }


        // count the repititons
        $count_val_time = array_count_values($time);

        // your required array
        $req_arr = array();

        foreach($temp_arr as $key=>$value)
        {
           $req_arr[$key] = $value/($count_val_time[$key]);
        }

        print_r($req_arr);

        ?>
```